# How to get File's atime and ctime (Crystal-lang)

Tags: crystal-lang

*(Newbie here).*

Trying to get a file's last **access_time** and **creation_time**. I have found how to get modification time thusly.

```
File.info("foo").modification_time
```

but cannot find anything for the other two. *(Using latest 0.28) on OSX High Sierra*.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there used to be `File.stat("foo").atime` and `File.stat("foo").ctime` (see [here](https://github.com/crystal-lang/crystal/blob/e2a1389e8165fb097c785524337d7bb7b550a086/src/file/stat.cr#L14) and [here](https://github.com/crystal-lang/crystal/blob/e2a1389e8165fb097c785524337d7bb7b550a086/src/file/stat.cr#L30)).

It looks like this was removed for portability reasons, see [this PR comment](https://github.com/crystal-lang/crystal/pull/5584#issuecomment-357505474).

Comment: Thanks.I am on OSX and `atime` is definitely giving correct information, and so is `ctime` (or birthtime). Sad that something should be dropped since some systems (Windows?? ) doesn't implement it.